# Is it possible to prevent signal condensation?

Tags: c++, linux, unix, signals

In C++ on Linux, from what I understand, if the same signal is delivered multiple times, it's possible that the signal handler will be called only once. Is it possible to override this behavior? Say, for example, that I have several file descriptors, and I want to be notified by a SIGIO whenever there are events on these file descriptors. So I call `fcntl` with the command `F_SETOWN_EX` on each of them. But if there are simultaneous events on 2 file descriptors I might get only one SIGIO and then never know that an event occoured on the other file descriptor.

Now I know you might wonder why I want to use signals at all, rather than jusgt `epoll` or something. The thing is I'm interested in the exact time that the events happen, so I was thinking of calling `clock_gettime` from the SIGIO signal handler to record the exact time of the event.

Comment: On Linux, you can use `sigaction` to configure a signal handler to *block* the signal while the handler is running; the signal is delivered to a thread that doesn't block it, or the first thread that unblocks it.

Comment: @Kerrek: So you're saying that If the same signal is sent twice to my process, and I have 2 threads which don't block it, than I'm guaranteed to receive the signal twice, perhaps in different threads?

Comment: No, I didn't say that, or mean to say that. Among the things I meant to say is that if your signal handler is installed with `sigaction` and an appropriate `sa_mask`, then one signal handler should be invoked for each delivered signal.

Comment: @Kerrek: Do u know any alternative way in which I can know when exactly, for example, data became available on a socket? Seems like `epoll` doesn't give me that information.

Comment: Seems like this isn't just an X-Y problem, but more like an X-Z problem. Epoll should give you all the facilities you need, *including* signal handling (with `signalfd`). Perhaps work through a few epoll tutorials in small steps?

Comment: @Kerrek: I'm already using `epoll` and `signalfd` successfully, and I think I understand them pretty well, but it seems like `epoll` can only tell me about events relating to the file descriptors, but not the exact **time** that an event happened. So I know, im my case, that a data is available for read on some socket, but not when exactly did this data become available.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but in case anyone still wonders: you should be able to accomplish what you want by using `fcntl` with `F_SETSIG` to select a real-time signal (a signal number >= `SIGRTMIN`), instead of using the default `SIGIO`.